# Applying an upper limit to a max calculation in MSSQL - something like Least()

Tags: sql-server

I understand MSSQL doesn't have a LEAST function, and that CASE provides a reasonable alternative, however, for some reason I am struggling to make that work.

Current code is:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@QueryStartDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(tt.Time as datetime) as  [Time],
    COALESCE(td.[Max Time],0) AS [Max Time]
```

And am trying to change to something like:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@QueryStartDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(tt.Time as datetime) as  [Time],
    CASE [Max Time] 
        WHEN td.[Max Time] > 9.00
        THEN 9.00 ELSE COALESCE(td.[Max Time],0)
    END
```

But can't seem to get it to work! If anyone can let me know where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the logic you want to implement? Is it (pseudo-code) IF `Max Time` > 9 THEN 9 IF `Max Time` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE `Max Time`?

Comment: ..., CASE 
        WHEN td.[Max Time] > 9.00
        THEN 9.00 ELSE COALESCE(td.[Max Time],0) END AS TheMaxTime,...

Comment: Thanks Andrew - that fixed it! @Nicky yes that was the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(null as float) as [Max Time] into #tmp
insert into #tmp select 3.0
insert into #tmp select 12.0

select * from #tmp

select case 
    when coalesce([max time], 0.0) < 9.0 then 9.0
    else [Max Time]
end
from #tmp
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - that does it too. Appreciate everyone's help